# $http.get returning malformed data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am learning Angular.js , today is my second day . Following is a simple function

```
var XApp = angular.module("XApp", ['ngResource']);

XApp.controller('MenuParentController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('api/menu?type=json').success(function (data) {
        console.log('Inside MenuParentController ' + JSON.parse(data));
        $scope.parentItems = JSON.parse(data);
     });

})
```

**Following is the output from console.log :**

```
Inside MenuParentController [{"NodeId":261,"ParentId":9,"NodeName":"Clothing"},{"NodeId":262,"ParentId":9,"NodeName":"Jewellery"},{"NodeId":263,"ParentId":9,"NodeName":"Bags"},{"NodeId":12,"ParentId":1,"NodeName":"Home Décor"},{"NodeId":10,"ParentId":1,"NodeName":"Stationery & Office Supplies"},{"NodeId":811,"ParentId":1,"NodeName":"Gifts"}]
```

**This is the error i get:**

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=item%20in%20parentItems&p1=string%3Ad
```

Doing `JSON.parse(data)[0]` gives `[` as output which is wrong. Rather it should have been `{"NodeId":261,"ParentId":9,"NodeName":"Clothing"}`

**HTML :**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in parentItems"><a href="/{{ item.NodeId }}/{{ item.NodeName }}" title="{{ item.NodeName }}" class="newMenuClass {{item.NodeName | lowercase }}">{{ item.NodeName }}</a></li>
```

Somehow Angular is treating each character of the JSON object as properties of the object . Any idea why?

**EDIT :**

When i use $.ajax everything works fine

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/menu?type=json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Inside MenuParentController ' + data);
            $scope.parentItems = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT 2 :**

When I hit `http://localhost:57086/api/menu?type=json` this is the output i get

```
"[{\"NodeId\":261,\"ParentId\":9,\"NodeName\":\"Clothing\"},{\"NodeId\":262,\"ParentId\":9,\"NodeName\":\"Jewellery\"},{\"NodeId\":263,\"ParentId\":9,\"NodeName\":\"Bags\"},{\"NodeId\":12,\"ParentId\":1,\"NodeName\":\"Home Décor\"},{\"NodeId\":10,\"ParentId\":1,\"NodeName\":\"Stationery & Office Supplies\"},{\"NodeId\":811,\"ParentId\":1,\"NodeName\":\"Gifts\"}]"
```

Comment: Please clarify the exact and whole server output that is returned by `api/menu?type=json`. Not from any log file, but from your browser's HTTP trace log. Angular is not doing any parsing, your browser's built-in JSON module is.

Comment: @DanielB I have added two edits to my question. Does this help ?

Comment: Is this really what is returned? That is a single string containing JSON. In other words, one layer of erroneous wrapping. It should look like `[{"NodeId":261,"ParentId":9,"NodeName":"Clothing"}, ...`.

Comment: @DanielB Yes that is what is returned. But how does it work wit $.ajax call ?

Comment: Because you're parsing twice there. Once implicitly by specifying `dataType: 'json'` and once explicitly inside the success callback method.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks a lot. Your suggestion solved the issue. By mistake i serialized the object unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right then.

The mistake was serializing the data twice, resulting in a single string containing the actual JSON data.

`$.ajax` with `dataType: 'json'` deserializes the data implicitly before passing it to the `success` callback. That's why the `JSON.parse` call there, being the second deserialization run, succeeded.